# Front-end, back-end or database: where should I generate data to create my components?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

I'm somewhat new to programming. We're creating an application using React, Redux and Django Rest Framework. The main goal of this application is to present educational data in a nice and comprehensible way. I'm using [Nivo](https://nivo.rocks/) to create all sorts of charts. Right now we're creating a simple line chart to show the score every school reached in a certain national test here. Nivo needs the data to generate the charts in this JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "japan",
    "color": "hsl(175, 70%, 50%)",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "plane",
        "y": 52
      },
      {
        "x": "helicopter",
        "y": 110
      },
      {
        "x": "boat",
        "y": 210
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

The data I have is something like this:

```
school_id   school_type   year   grade   first_application_score   second_aplication_score  avg
   1           public     2015     3             6.5                     7.2                6.9
   1           public     2016     4             7.9                     7.1                7.5
   2           private    2015     5             5.5                     6.5                6.0
```

My question here is: **where should I generate the data to create the chart's data?** In my actual level of understanding web programming, I could use the following strategies:

1. **I can create new tables in the database using SQL:** This tables will have the x and y values, so the API in Django will do no calculations, just send the static data sent from the database;
2. **I can do it in Django:** Django will receive the data as show in the table above, process everything and give back via API the data in the right format for Nivo to generate the chart;
3. **I can do it in React-Redux:** The data send via Django API will be exactly like the table above, and I pass it through some Redux middleware that change everything and React generate the chart.

What is the best strategy? What could be the worst strategy and why? What choice will present as the most consistent approach and why?

Comment: Keep in mind *changing requirements*: you may only be using the data for specific charts now, but in the future you or someone else may want to use it for other purposes as well. Then you’re in a bit of a pickle if your backend formats the data specifically for a specific front end component.

Comment: Do you want to create graphs from the above data?

Comment: @AkshatZala yes, I want to create a historical line showing which score some school get in a specific year. The x axis will be the years and the y axis will be the scores, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, as you'd probably  have guessed, a matter of personal preference and depends heavily on your specific use case.

Some considerations:

- The structure in which you want to store your data does not necessarily translate very well into the structure you use for building/showing your chart, so I would separate the two completely. Store the data in your dbase in one way, and write a few methods to prepare the data for the chart library.
- A `REST API` should follow rather strict principles regarding how data is retrieved, updated, created and deleted. Maybe read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) for some principle guidelines and methods on how to create a meaningful `API`.
- Think about how many people will access your backend and how much compute power is needed to prepare your data. If the 'translation' between SQL data and chart data takes a considerable amount of time, maybe it is better to offload this logic towards the client, as it frees up resources of your backend. If it's simply a matter of putting together a `JSON` response, you could do it in the backend.

It all boils down to the question *Where do you want your logic to be? In the backend? Or in the frontend?*

I think I would go with your second option:

1. Store the data in the database by creating appropriate models (Django)
2. Create a meaningful API that allows access to the data, probably by using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html)
   Depending on how many types of charts you need (and how often you plan to change this) I would create endpoints which deliver the prepared data (ready for use in the frontend by the chart library) with a request like that:

`GET https://your-backend.com/api/v1/data/nationaltest?begin=2019-01-01&end=2019-12-31`

By using filters, you could also write logic that includes/excludes certain data fields (like names, or anonymized data for un-privileged users and so on)